# Why Cassandra creates a separate .db file every time nodetool flush is called?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am learning Cassandra 3.x. I create a keyspace, a table and then I write it to disk using:
 `nodetool flush`

This creates among other files, a mc-1-big-Data.db file.
It seems that every time I write to disk using nodetool flush, it will create a new file? How is this efficient? Does it not mean that when I query data, it may have to go through multiple files to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each **Data.db file is actually a SSTable file. Cassandra stores its data  across multiple SSTTables. When cassandra is processing writes it is writing it to a SortStrings Table in memory  (SSTable=db file) and flushes them to disk periodically or on nodetool flush. Each flush will create a new SSTable on disk and the memory SSTable is cleared.

It won't go and update to existing SSTable file.
For more on files per column family (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html)

Later on during compaction one or more of these SSTables are merged based on merge policy to lessen the number of SSTable files.

All this is done typically by most big data system which support very high writes at low latency and also because editing files in place would be prohibitive in case of big data systems (because they store data in files on disk).

Hbase has Hfiles, Elasticsearch/Lucene has ES Segment files for e.g.